# Frame Redirect to .Net site from a sub domain hosted on Linux host SEO hit in 1and1?

Tags: apache, iis, subdomain, web-hosting, windows-hosting

My host : 1and1.com

My setup : I have my main domain and a sub domain hosted on the Linux host.

What I need : Sub domain (currently on Linux host) should be pointed to that of a .Net site hosted on MS Business hosting on 1and1. What is the best way of achieving it?

What I did so far : Used Frame redirect (from Sub domain to .Net site) and my client is pissed that SEO will take a hit. And he is calling me a lousy programmer!

Suggestions, comments, solutions greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is the problem`?

Domain X.com

Subdomain: Y.X.com

Point Y.X.com to the IP address of the windows host. Set up windows host to react to Y.X.com.

Finished.

Client should not call you a lousy programmer - but someone without a clue about how website technology works, internet wise. Note that this is different from Programming, it basically points to your administration skills (DNS, server setup etc.).

Comment: Oh trust me, I have explored those options. 1and1 is the problem here. I cannot point a sub domain to an IP address (in this case a .Net site hosted on a different MS platform at 1and1). 

The only options I had were frame/http redirect.

Comment: So get a proper host. Seriously. A hoster not allowing me to point a subdomain to their web server is crap crap crap.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe 1and1 prevent you from properly managing your DNS. This FAQ seems to indicate a fairly wide set of features that you'd expect from any hosting company, including being able to configure your sub-domain:

> http://faq.oneandone.co.uk/domains/dns_settings/index.html

Comment: Have been on phone for so long. They say Linux and MS Hosting can do nothing with eachother, no pointing subdomains, no database access...crap! I had to code a whole hack just to synchronize data from MySQL to SQL Server - both hosted by the same host in different environments.

Answer (score 0):

Select your domain by checking the box on the domain tab, then click on the DNS button.

Edit DNS settings

Name Server* : My Name Server and then enter in the information for:

```
Primary name server 
Secondary name server   
1st secondary name server   
2nd secondary name server   
3rd secondary name server
```

You should be able to do that no problem. Maybe it's the fact that IIS is involved with a Linux package? But that shouldn't make a difference at all. It's simply forwarding the DNS over to the next host.

I switched over to their Virtual Private Server because I can host multiple domains, full ASP.net control (ports, etc, no trust issues), and because I physically edit my SQL database rather than use their junk SQL web interface.